# Problema PL SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo la tabla Profesor, Alumno, Apoderado y User.

Necesito que al momento de ingresar un profesor, alumno o apoderado a la base de datos, se registre su usuario el cual se compondrá de la siguiente forma:

La tabla User tiene 4 columnas (ID,USER,CONTRASEÑA,TIPOUSUARIO) el tipousuario dependerá de que tabla se ingrese un registro el id sera de un incrementable de 1 en 1, el usuario se compondra de varias concatenaciones de substr. Mi duda es que si debo hacer un trigger o algo mas, soy nuevo en programación de base de datos, uso ORACLE.

ACTUALIZACION...
INTENTE LO DE ABAJO PERO TAMPOCO TUVE RESULTADO:

````sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_USER
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_USER_APODERADOO
  AFTER INSERT ON APODERADO
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_USER VARCHAR (20);
V_CONTRASENA VARCHAR(20);
V_TIPO VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTR(P_NOMBRE,1,2)||'_'||ap_materno,
            SUBSTR(S_NOMBRE(1,3))||SUBSTR(RUT_APODERADO,-1,-3)||'.'
    INTO    V_USER,
            V_CONTRASENA
    FROM APODERADO;
V_TIPO:= APODERADO;
INSERT INTO "USER" VALUES(SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL,V_USER,V_CONTRASENA,V_TIPO);
END TRG_USER_APODERADOO;```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Depende lo que diga tu ejercicio...

Comment: Cuando usas un trigger y quieres utilizar los valores que se han introducido no tienes que hacer un select ya que todavía no ha llegado a la tabla. Tienes que usar :new.campo si usas un trigger after insert. Busca ejemplos de trigger after insert y lo verás